# java - read user input and print line if it is a duplicate

Tags: java, text, readline

So I'm learning about reading text files in java and I'm trying to write a program that reads user input one line at a time and outputs the current line if and only if it is a duplicate of some previous line. This is the part of code I'm struggling with and was wondering if I could get a push in the right direction. Right now it currently asks for user input, and when I write a line and press enter, the program ends without printing anything.

```
public static void doIt(BufferedReader r, PrintWriter w) throws IOException {
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();


    while(true) {
        String line = r.readLine();
        if(s.contains(line)) {
            s.add(line);
        }else {
            break;
        }
    }


    for (String text : s) {
        w.println(text);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but i can help you figure out why it doesnt print anything. Your code is basically : if S contains the text you just read, add it in the set. But since S is empty (you just create it) it will never add anything because he will not find any dupes. you could get another Set thats keep in memory every text you wrote and compare text with that set to know if you need to add to S.

Comment: The `s.add(line);` will be never reached, so `s` will be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep two mutable states, one for all the lines and one for duplicate lines.

Example below. (You can exit program on `:q`).

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CheckDupes {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Set<String> lines = new HashSet<String>();
        Set<String> duplicateLines = new HashSet<String>();

        BufferedReader stdReader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String line = null;
        while (!(line = stdReader.readLine()).equals(":q")) {
            if (lines.contains(line)) {
                duplicateLines.add(line);
            } else {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        }

        duplicateLines.forEach(l -> System.out.println(l));
    }

}
```

**Input/ Output**

```
love is great
weather is good
software is version 4
weather is good
love is great
:q
weather is good
love is great
```